Google Sheets formula that will check if cells in two separate tabs match, then pull the data from a 3rd different column into 1st tab
Going to try and put this into words as best as I can, so bear with me please...
I have a Google Sheet with four different tabs; the 'MainTab' and three separate reference tabs with different pieces of data from elsewhere I'd like to pull data from to consolidate into 'MainTab'.
I want to create a column in 'MainTab' that looks up if the text in Column B of 'MainTab' matches the text of column B in 'SecondTab', then pull in text from Column C in 'SecondTab' into Column C of 'MainTab'.
E.g:
'MainTab' has a list of data on suburbs including suburb names, but is missing 'postcodes/zip codes'. I have downloaded a master list of postcodes from elsewhere in 'SecondTab' that also has suburb names, but don't want to go through one by one and copy-paste every zip code into 'MainTab'.
So I want to create a column called 'Zip Code' into 'MainTab' and have it look up Zip Code in 'SecondTab' to pull in the correct zip code to that column only IF the suburb name in Suburb column are the same in each of 'MainTab' and 'SecondTab'.
So basically: IF SuburbName from MainTab = SuburbName from SecondTab, THEN ZipCode from MainTab = ZipCode from SecondTab... and have it automatically insert all the correct zip codes.
Tried various VLOOKUPs etc. demonstrated online, but they only seem to deal with pulling data from one column in a tab into another equivalent column in a different tab, rather than 'if two columns in two different tabs match, then pull data from a third column.'

Use INDEX/MATCH functions.

Or perhaps EXACT to compare the two values and wrap it in an IF to get the third value if EXACT is true.

@Tedinoz - that sounds like what I'm aiming for, do you have an example of what such a code snippet might look like please?

Try this formula in Cell B2 of "Main Tab".
=map(A2:A,lambda(a,if((a=""),,iferror(vlookup(a,{SecondTab!B:B,SecondTab!A:A},2,0),"-"))))
h/t @rockinfreakshow for formula logic in Multiple Vlookup in google sheets

SAMPLE - Main Tab


SAMPLE - Second Tab

